# In one Function What I do change different color of background regarding on card hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objects

**In one Function What I do change different color of background regarding on card hover.**
*In this Code I need only one function for when hover on card then image is display on background*

> bicycle image = color on background
>
> **Use Only one Function For All Images changing on background according to card **

**My Code Is Started Here**

```js
const allcards = document.querySelectorAll('.card-inner .card');
for (i = 0; i < allcards.length; i++) {
  allcards[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    const image = document.querySelectorAll('.card-inner .img');
    for (j = 0; j < image.length; j++) {
      image[j].style.opacity = "100%";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contaner {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

.card {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.img {
  border: 5px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0%;
  transition: 1s;
}

.img1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.img2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.img3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.img4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.card-inner {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contaner">
  <div class="card-inner">
    <div class="img1 img"></div>
    <div class="card1 card">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-inner">
    <div class="img2 img"></div>
    <div class="card2 card">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-inner">
    <div class="img3 img"></div>
    <div class="card3 card">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-inner">
    <div class="img4 img"></div>
    <div class="card4 card">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript for changing the color?

`.card-inner:hover > div.img { background-color: #CCC; }`

Comment: And if you need more, then delegate: `document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('.card');   if (tgt) /* do something with card */
});`

Comment: You really need to declare your variables. Make sure you declare i and j. The event object gives you info about the element you are on. `allcards[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { console.log(e.currentTarget);`

Comment: in code we have 4 cards on hover a card 1 = green, card 2 = red, card 3 = blue, card 4 = yellow **Change a color on card hover like this**

Comment: please give me full answer with code

Comment: please sir give me this code **working code**